# How to use isnull() in a varchar query sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exec, concatenation, isnull

I build a query within a variable of type `varchar` I want to make test with `isnull()` 
example:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = '
Select top (100) id
FROM RIGHT R  inner join RIGHT_TYPE RT on 
R.RIGHT_TYPE_CODE = RT.CODE
WHERE R.RIGHT_TYPE_CODE = isnull('+@rightType+', R.RIGHT_TYPE_CODE)
'
exec (@sql)
go
```

`@rightType` is a parameter of my stored procedure.
The problem that when I have `@rightType` equals to null nothings works
Thank you.

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: So, what is your question here, you haven't asked one. On a different note, concatenating values to create a query is a bad idea; it just leaves you open to injection. I suggest parametrising your query.

Comment: Is this your way to make an optional parameter, give a `null` if it's not supposed to be used?

Comment: the problem is when I have @rightType equals null nothing works

Comment: @JamesZ Yes exactly  make an optional parameter

Comment: Why use dynamic sql at all? There is nothing in the code posted that suggests you need dynamic sql here.

Comment: @SeanLange It's just example where I have the problem the stored procedure is more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have optional parameters in dynamic SQL, this is usually the best option:

```
DECLARE @rightType nvarchar(50)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
    Select top (100) id
    FROM RIGHT R  inner join RIGHT_TYPE RT on 
    R.RIGHT_TYPE_CODE = RT.CODE
    WHERE 1=1'

if (@rightType is not NULL) set @sql = @sql + ' and R.RIGHT_TYPE_CODE = @rightType'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@rightType nvarchar(50)', @rightType
```

This way you're not concatenating the input string with the SQL, so there's no chance of SQL injection happening, and the optimizer likes this a lot more, because the parameter is in the SQL only when it's actually given.

The `1=1` is in the SQL so that you can append any number (or none) criteria to the SQL without having to worry to have correct amount of `and`s.